# How to split QStringList with more than one delimeter?

Tags: c++, qt, split, qstring, qregexp

I am trying to use `split()` function in `QStringList`

I have such a file;

```
41761505526;31.8
55201481028;69.5
26458795084;14.2
26410796678;29.4
```

I want to split those numbers like;

```
    41761505526     31.8
    55201481028     69.5
    26458795084     14.2
    26410796678     29.4
```

However I dont know how to use split function with 2 delimeter.

If I use;

```
strList = str.split(";");
```

Then it will show like

```
    41761505526
31.855201481028
69.526458795084
14.226410796678
29.4
```

I used `str.split("\\W+");`  it works not bad however not it is also splitting `(.) dat` char too. What is the most suitable way to split more than one delimeter ?

Comment: I can't find `split` function in documentation of `QStringList`. You mean `split` in `QString`?

Comment: @stamaimer yes.. I am trying to create QStringList using QString.split()

Comment: how about to split with `;` line by line or split whole string with line breaker first and then split the QStringList elements with `;`?

Comment: Try `strList = str.split(QRegExp("(\\;|\\n)"));` (Comment because I'm not sure about that regex!)

Comment: @acraig5075 thank you, or works in QRegExp()